# check multiple conditions in excel and return column name

Tags: excel, ms-office, excel-2010

Hello I have four columns in excel.
in the fifth column I need to store the column name which is having value as 1 (only one will have 1)

```
=IF(A=1, "A", "False")
```

What i want to acheive is, I want to set the column name which has 1 in it
do i need to do the above formula four times ?! please help

```
if A=1 return A
if B=1 return B
if C=1 return C
if D=1 return D
```

Comment: What do you want to use the result for? I have the slight suspicion that the column name is only an intermediate step. In this case, you might not even need it, as there might be better ways...

Comment: I actually wanted to set as 1/2/3/4 based on column names ! :)

Comment: then `=MATCH(1,A1:D1,0)`should be sufficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this formula:

```
=CHOOSE(MATCH(1,A1:D1,0),"A","B","C","D")
```

alternatively, this will also work:

```
=CHAR(64+MATCH(1,A1:D1,0))
```

Comment: awesome thanks !!
I want to learn these formulae. if you can, please provide me a link :)

Comment: Sorry, wouldn't know a link... When stumbling upon a formula I do not know, I simple use the Excel Help to understand it...